# mmenu plugin is not used in ASP.NET MVC Home\Index page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, adminlte, mmenu

I want to use mmenu plugin on asp.net mvc at home \ index page. For this, I included the plugin in my adminLTE v.3 (bootstrap v4) themed project. But when the plugin works, it takes over the body and the menu starts working right inside the body. But where it should work is home \ index. What kind of setting should I make for this? I want help from those who use this plugin.

*****UPDATED Paint drawn exactly what I want**

[image]

**my original AdminLTE template;**

[image]

**mispositioned mmenu;**

[image]

**original mmenu**
[image]

**The styles that mmenu creates inside the body of asp.net mvc**
[image]

**Home\Index.cshtml**

```
@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/mmenu/demo/css/demo.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/mmenu/dist/mmenu.css" />


<div id="page">
<div class="header">
    <a href="#menu"><span></span></a>
    Demo
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>
        <strong>This is a demo.</strong><br />
        Click the menu icon to open the menu.
    </p>
</div>
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <span>About us</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#about/history">History</a></li>
                <li>
                    <span>The team</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#about/team/management">Management</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#about/team/sales">Sales</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#about/team/development">Development</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#about/address">Our address</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

        <li class="Divider">Other demos</li>
        <li><a href="advanced.html">Advanced demo</a></li>
        <li><a href="onepage.html">One page demo</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
@section Scripts
{<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        const menu = new Mmenu(
            document.querySelector('#menu')
        );
    });
 </script>
}
<script src="~/mmenu/dist/mmenu.polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="~/mmenu/dist/mmenu.js"></script>
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>@ViewBag.Title - Merinos Tablet</title>
 <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
 <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_Header")
    @Html.Partial("_Sidebar")

    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <div class="content-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">@ViewBag.Title</h1>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                                
@Html.ActionLink(@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), 
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"])
                            </li>
                            @*@if (@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() != "Dashboard" ||
                                     @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() != "Dashboard")
                                {

                                }*@
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">@ViewBag.Title</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.content-header -->
        <!-- Main content -->
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                @RenderBody()
                <!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.content -->
    </div>

    @Html.Partial("_Footer")
    @Html.Partial("_Aside")
</div>
<!-- REQUIRED SCRIPTS -->
<!-- jQuery -->
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/adminlte/js")

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**mmenu.demo.css**

```
.header,
.content,
.footer {
  text-align: center;
}
.header,
.footer {
    background: #4bb5ef;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 44px;

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 44px;
    padding: 0 50px;
}
.header.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.footer.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.header a {
    display: block;
    width: 28px;
    height: 18px;
    padding: 11px;
    margin: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.header a:before,
.header a:after {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     background: #fff;
     height: 2px;
 }
 .header a span {
     background: #fff;
     display: block;
     height: 2px;
     margin: 6px 0;
 }
.content {
padding: 150px 50px 50px 50px;
}
```

Comment: I think the best approach to devide template, you need to put template related things in layout and then directly use same layout in index page. this is the normal approach we use. Have you tried that?

Comment: I updated the post with visuals. I tried what you said but there seems to be a style problem. When the plugin is initialized, it is placed directly inside the body tag.

Comment: After gone through you visual, i can say due to header and sidebar partial view causes the issue. Try to comment header and sidebar in layout file and then try load the Home/Index page, check anything update or not?

Comment: I did not understand what you said last.

Comment: Okay, Just do one thing, in layout.cshtml page comment @Html.Partial("_Header") &
    @Html.Partial("_Sidebar")  lines and then try to reload Home/Index page.

Comment: I understand what you said, but I want both sidebars to remain. Both adminLTE and mmenu sidebar should remain. If I comment out the lines you said, I will lose the adminlte sidebar and hedaer.
please see my last update.